# Debugging xv6 kernel with gdb - Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture

Tags: gdb, xv6

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04 host and try to remote debug xv6 kernel running locally under qemu emulator.

I run :

1. gdb kernel
2. target remote localhost:26000

I get :

**Remote debugging using localhost:26000
warning: Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64
warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
Remote 'g' packet reply is too long (expected 312 bytes, got 608 bytes): 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006306000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f0ff0000000000000200000000f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007f0300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000801f0000
(gdb)**

Any idea how can I solve this problem ?

Thanks!

Gil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command in gdb:

```
(gdb) set architecture i386:x86-64
```

This solved it for me.